# Set focus to AciveX text Box with VBA

Tags: excel, textbox, setfocus, vba

I'd like to set-focus to a text box placed in a worksheet (not on a form) using vba, or any other method without using the mouse.

The SetFocus function is not available in that situation, unlike when the text box is placed on a user form.

The purpose is to move the cursor to the text box, so typing will type in the TB and not on the sheet.
excel 2010.

Is it possible to do that?

tx

Comment: Macro Recorder. `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("TextBoxName").Select` ?

Comment: I can use the select directly txt.Select... I probably wasn't clear enough. The purpose is to type text directly in the text box, without setting the cursor inside with the mouse. Calling Select will set the focus to the text box, but it is still impossible to type text in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Activate method of the textbox.